# Removing an event handler by setting null is not working in Firefox 3.6

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I was experimenting this code. It worked well in Chrome but not in Firefox 3.6

```
<body onmousedown="return false" oncontextmenu="return false">
<p>once there lived</p>
<div style='color:red; height: 300px; width:100%;'>
hehe</div>

<script>
/*
window.setTimeout( function() {
     document.body.onmousedown = function() { return true; }
     document.body.oncontextmenu = function() { return true; }
     document.onmousedown = function() { return true; }
     document.oncontextmenu = function() { return true; }
     alert('ready to check');
},5000)
*/

window.setTimeout( function() {
     document.body.onmousedown = null;
     document.body.oncontextmenu = null;
     document.onmousedown = null;
     document.oncontextmenu = null;
     alert('ready to check');
},5000)

</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Gecko-based browsers `<body onmousedown>` maps to `window.onmousedown`, not `document.onmousedown` or `document.body.onmousedown`. On other elements the mousedown element maps to the mousedown property as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that should be working. Firefox has an option to not allow JavaScript to disable/replace context menus -- perhaps you have that set?

Comment: I did not do any modifications in firefox. let me try in another version.